# Play framework - save data to database by parameters in URL

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.2

I'm new to the Play Framework, and Scala language. I want to save some data to database only by running URL with specified parameters. 
For example I want to run url like:

> /DeviceData?device_ID=1&insertDate=2013-01-01&windDirection=50&device_ID=1&insertDate=2013-01-02&windDirection=5

and after that in the database two new records would be inserted (with Device_ID, insertDate and windDirection).
Right now I'm trying to save only one record at once (I don't know how to read list of elements and save them) but event that it's not working. There is no error, it's just not inserted.

DeviceData model

```
    case class DeviceData(data_ID: Long, device_ID: Long, insertDate: String, windDirection: Double)

object DeviceData{
    var deviceDataList = new HashMap[Long, DeviceData]
    var data_ID = 0L

    def nextId(): Long = { data_ID += 1; data_ID}

    def createDeviceData(device_ID: Long, insertDate: String, windDirection: Double) :Unit = { 
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
            SQL(
                """
                    INSERT INTO devicedata(device_ID, insertDate, windDirection) 
                    VALUES ({device_ID}, {insertDate}, {windDirection})
                """
            ).
            on("device_ID" -> device_ID, "insertDate" -> insertDate, "windDirection" -> windDirection).
            executeInsert()
        }
    }

    def list(): List[DeviceData] = { deviceDataList.values.toList }
}
```

DeviceDatas controller

```
    object DeviceDatas extends Controller {

  val deviceDataForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "device_ID" -> of[Long],
      "insertDate" -> nonEmptyText,
      "windDirection" -> of[Double]
    )
  )

  def listDeviceData() = Action {
    Ok(views.html.deviceData(DeviceData.list(), deviceDataForm))
  }

    def createDeviceData(device_ID: Long, insertDate: String, windDirection: Double) = Action { implicit request =>
      deviceDataForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors => BadRequest(views.html.deviceData(DeviceData.list(), errors)),
        { case (device_ID, insertDate, windDirection) => {
            DeviceData.createDeviceData(device_ID, insertDate, windDirection)
            Redirect(routes.DeviceDatas.listDeviceData)
          }
        }
     )
  }
}
```

deviceData.scala.html - it's simple one, just to check if there is any new inserted record.

```
    @(deviceDatas: List[DeviceData], deviceDataForm: Form[(Long, String, Double)])

@import helper._

@main("DeviceDatas"){
    <h3>@deviceDatas.size DeviceData(s)</h3>
}
```

routes file for /deviceDatas

```
 GET    /deviceDatas                controllers.DeviceDatas.listDeviceData
POST    /deviceDatas                controllers.DeviceDatas.createDeviceData(device_ID: Long, insertDate: String, windDirection: Double)
```

Could You help me with that how to insert the data into database, and if there is any possibility to put list of elements with few records to insert. Also what's the best way to insert DateTime (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) into URL parameters in Play Framework? I'm stuck and I don't know how to do it.

**UPDATED**

Thanks Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot for the answer. Unfortunately I need to use parameters, because I'm sending the data through the router. But anyway one more thanks to You because I'll use json in the future. 
I decided to not use List of parameter as I said before, but for one new record I'm sending one request (for example: to add 6 new records to the database I need to run 6 times URL on the router:

```
/DeviceData?device_ID=1&insertDate=2013-01-01&windDirection=50
```

And my problem was solved by changing the route file to:

```
GET     /deviceDatas                controllers.DeviceDatas.listDeviceData
GET     /deviceDatas                controllers.DeviceDatas.createDeviceData(device_ID: Long, insertDate: String, windDirection: Double)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: There was no error, just nothing happened, and record was not added to the database

Answer (score 0):

To pass in data for multiple records, and also to pass in DateTime data, send the data in the request's json body instead of as url params

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaBodyParsers

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson

```
Action(parse.json) { implicit request => 
  (request.body \ "records") match {
    case arr: JsArray => arr.value.foreach(json => {
      val deviceId = (json \ "device_ID").as[Long]
      val date = (json \ "insertDate").as[String]
      val windDirection = (json \ "windDirection").as[Double]
      // insert data in database
    })
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Json: records must be a JsArray")
}}
```

The json for your records might look something like

```
{"records" : [
  {"device_ID" : 123, "insertDate" : "2014-03-01 12:00:00", "windDirection" : 123.45},
  {"device_ID" : 456, "insertDate" : "2014-03-02 12:00:00", "windDirection" : 54.321}]}
```